# LinkedIn api v2 serviceErrorCode:65603 message:Multiple access token provided

Tags: linkedin-api

After LinkedIn changed his API to v2 my users cannot login on my website anymore. The error message is

> Multiple access token provided

With LinkedIn v1 API everything was good. For development purpose I added a second app in my LinkedIn account with a subdomain of the original domain. With the "subdomain"-app I received the error message that v1 is not supported anymore. The "original" domain app still worked with v1 until a couple of days ago. I adjusted the request to v2 and I received the error message "Multiple access token provided". I deleted the subdomain app, but the error still occurred.

With:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&format=json&access_token=xxxx
```

I receive:

```
"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/access_token, /format]","status":403
```

I changed the access token name to `oauth2_access_token`:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&format=json&oauth2_access_token=xxxxx
```

I receive:

```
serviceErrorCode":65603,"message":"Multiple access token provided","status":401
```

What do I have to do, to provide just one (the right) access token?

Comment: The second call works fine for me (with a valid token) removing the `&format=json` params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access token needs to be included in the `Authorization: Bearer {token}` header of your request. You do not need to append the `format=json` query parameter as all API responses are returned in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, but unfortunately the header is already set like you suggested. I removed the format parameter but still doesn't work.

Comment: If you're seeing the "Multiple access token provided" response, you are providing the access token in both the query param and request header. The access token must be in the header only.

Comment: Hey Christopher, you made my day. That was the missing pice. Now it works! Thank you a lot. "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}" and remove the access_token form the get-parameters.